# How to get historic Step data from HealthKit

Tags: ios, react-native, healthkit

I want to fetch historic pedometer data from HealthKit. But documentation states that only the last seven days are available.

The thing is: other apps exist, that plot years of data of mine.

Does anyone have suggestion on how to access older data?

Comment: can you post the documentation? I don't think there are limits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were reading CoreMotion documentation. There it says, that the data from Pedometer is saved on the device for the last 7 days.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer/1613946-querypedometerdatafromdate?language=objc

For HealthKit there is no such a limit. You can fetch the data from Health App for a couple of years if you have it. You just specify the time interval you are interested and query the data using, for example, HKSampleQuery.
Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksamplequery